# Regression of the form $y=a-be^{-x}$

Tags: exponential-function, regression, least-squares, data-analysis

Say we have the points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$ and we need to find the best fit equation that is of the form $y=a-be^{-x}$ (the red curve). See the illustration plot:

[image]

Based on least-squares, how to get the values of $a$ and $b$, theoretically, without using softwares?

Your help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t_i=e^{-x_i}$ and the model is just
$$y=a-bt$$ which is easy.

Comment: Thanks dear, I will try it now. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this easy way. I believe you can also help me in this problem. THANKS IN ADVANCE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463981/is-there-a-general-way-to-determine-the-best-combination-of-parameters-to-fit-po

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari. Done !

Answer (score 1):

You have $a$ and $b$ as linear coefficients, meaning that
$$
a\cdot x_m+b\cdot e^{-x_m} = y_m
$$
should be fulfilled for every $m\in \{1, \cdots, n\}$. 
Rewriting this as a matrix equation gives
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}x_1 &e^{-x_1} \\ x_2 &e^{-x_2}\\ \vdots \\ x_n &e^{-x_n}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}y_1\\\vdots \\y_n \end{pmatrix}\\
A\cdot x &= b
\end{align}
which is an over-determined system of linear equations with no guaranteed solution (at least if $n>2$).

In order to obtain a least-squares solution with minimal $\|Ax-b\|_2$, you usually set up normal equations $A^TA x=A^Tb$ and solve them. 
ou can alleviate numerical instabilities by using the QR-decomposition of $A$, but this is definitely not advisable by hand.